# How can I run only integration tests

Tags: rust

Is there a way to only run integration tests, but not unit-tests?

I've tried:

`cargo test --tests`: runs unit + integration tests

`cargo test --test test_name`: runs one specified test

Is it currently not possible to only run integration tests or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You could adopt a naming policy whereby you name all integration tests with a specific pattern and then use `cargo test pattern`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can run ONLY the integration tests by:

```sh
cargo test --test '*'
```

Please note that only `'*'` will work; neither `*` nor `"*"` works.

Reference: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8396

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: In my testing with cargo watch I found `cargo test --test *` to work.

Comment: You can use `cargo test --test *`, `cargo test --test '*'` or `cargo test --test "*"` to run integration tests. All produce the same result.

Comment: In posix shells, `'*'` and `"*"` are the same, and `*` (glob) almost certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, Cargo doesn't really distinguish between integration tests and unit tests, since there isn't a real difference between the two in terms of how you manage and implement them; the difference is purely semantic. Not all codebases even have that separation. The book and the reference call them unit tests and integration tests for simplicity and to avoid confusion, but technically there is no such distinction.

Instead of separating tests into two logical categories, Cargo has a flexible filtering system, which allows you to only run tests when their name matches a certain pattern. The [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html) has a section dedicated to this system. If you'd like to filter out certain tests because they took a long time to run or are otherwise undesirable to be run along with all others, annotate a test with `#[ignore]`. Otherwise, use a certain naming methodology for the tests so that you can filter them out by their name.

The [Cargo reference page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html) also mentions the fact that you can use the target options in the `Cargo.toml` manifest to control what is run when you use `--tests`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to supplement answer.
If you need to run **only ONE integration test method** (e.g. 'intergration_test_method') you can do that by following command:

```
cargo test --test integration_tests 'intergration_test_method' 

cargo test --test integration_tests 'intergration_test_method' -- --nocapture
```